Excel sheet refreshed using Python. Not able to use data until program is closed and reopened
I have a Python program connected to an excel spreadsheet. That spreadsheet gets data from a spreadsheet on a server. There are several columns with text information and a date column. My python gui interface has a refresh button among others. It refreshes my sheet correctly. I have another field where I choose the date of the newest information added, and that should populate another excel sheet. When I run the program and refresh the sheet, the newest information will not populate the next sheet. If I choose an older date it works. If i close the program and rerun it, then the newest information that was added will be added when the date is chosen. I have tried several variations of the code below, and the result is the same. The newest information added is unavailable until I close the program and rerun it.
def refresh_excel_connections(file_name):
    # Create a new instance of Excel
    xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")

    try:
        # Open the specific workbook
        xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(file_name)

        # Refresh all data connections
        xlwb.RefreshAll()

        # Ensure all asynchronous queries are done calculating
        xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()

        # Save the workbook
        xlwb.Save()

    finally:
        # Close the workbook
        xlwb.Close(SaveChanges=False)

        # Quit the application
        xlapp.Quit()

refresh_excel_connections(file_name)

